# Combination of I-130 and J1

Tags: j1-visas

I am a naturalized US citizen, and this past January have started a process to sponsor my brother for US permanent residency. His case is still processing and has not been approved yet, it usually takes about a year.

However, in the meantime, my brother received an offer on his own to spend time in the US on a J1, exchange visitor visa, which is a non-immigrant visa.

Is his J1 approval jeopardized by the fact that there is an apparent immigrant intent?

Comment: This would fit better on [Expatriates.SE].  Your brother won't likely be able to immigrate for more than a decade, so if he can convince the visa officer that he won't seek to immigrate *during his J-1 visit,* he should be fine.  That could be a big *if,* however.

Comment: what @phoog mentioned + if an I-130 is already filed proving a nonimmigrant intent for a J1 will be really hard. Also, an I-130 may take about 12+ years from filing to visa availability depending on which country your brother is from.

Comment: Just an update, this ended well, and my brother and his family have been granted J1 (J2) visas.